# How to implement a If Else Condition inside of new List()

Tags: asp.net-core

I was trying to make a condition if "data" is equals to "2" inside of `List<T>`

```
List<TransmissionRes> rawr = new List<TransmissionRes>();
rawr = (from DataRow dr in table.Rows
      select new TransmissionRes()
      {
         if(data == "2") FailureCount = dr.Field<string>("FailureCount")
         //FailureCount = data == "2" ? true : dr.Field<string>("FailureCount")
      }).ToList();
return rawr;
```

Those both I tried didn't work for my condition, is there any other way? my "data condition" is something like

```
if(data == "1") (some codes here) else if(data == "2") (It will go right here)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by only changing the query as

```
FailureCount = data == "2" ? dr.Field<string>("FailureCount") : ""
```

Comment: I think you should wait 2 days and [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)